# Purge purgeable pages from memory in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory

I was reading [this](http://gamesfromwithin.com/whered-that-memory-go) interesting article regarding the display of the memory parameters in the iPhone and I noticed that among the various data return in addition to "active" "physical" "free" etc. etc. there is also the "purgeable" (const int = purgeablePages vmStats. purgeable_count;), I was wondering since this is precisely "purgeable" how is possible purge it? There is a command in objective-c to do this?

Thanks at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are kernel memory management statistics. The purgeable memory pages can be freed and thus reused by the kernel at any time. Since this is a kernel-internal thing and the related memory likely doesn't belong to your process (if you haven't allocated it) you cannot influence it.

You can allocate purgeable memory through `vm_allocate`, but this [isn't really documented](http://osdir.com/ml/darwin-dev/2009-09/msg00120.html) and you are *very* unlikely to ever need it. The best "documentation" available seems to be a [WebKit class that uses purgeable memory](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-528.14/platform/mac/PurgeableBufferMac.cpp).